# Android app tutorial pages for first time when app launches

Tags: java, android

I m new in android development i want to create (app tutorial page) which is shows for first time when app launches. and after login in my app the app tutorial not shows second time when the user again start the app. If u have know any app example then help me.Thank u in Advance.

Comment: persist a Boolean in Shared preference..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a SharedPreferences instance and put a flag when you have successfully logged in (in your splash screen Activity - Launcher Activity). Update this flag when user logs in successfully. and check at the app launch what this flag value is. So accordingly you can navigate to activity skipping this activity (which you want to show only once). I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The most common approach for this is to use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store some sort of a flag (after the tutorial has been seen by the user), for example:

```
boolean tutorialSeen;
```

When starting an app you should check if this value has been stored in `SharedPreferences`, and if not - you should display tutorial.

Comment: would u tell me any example/demo app project  available on internet

Comment: Read developer docs on `SharedPreferences`, read other answers and try your best writing your code. It's really not that difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Use Android's SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("tutorials", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean tutorialSeen = sp.getBoolean("tutorialSeen", false); //will return false if there is no shared preference with name tutorialSeen 
if(!tutorialSeen){
    showTutorial();
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
    ed.putBoolean("tutorialSeen", true);
    ed.commit();
}
```

Comment: would u tell me any example/demo app project available on internet

Answer (score 1):

As [blipinsk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29914668/1993204) said use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Example :

Check user logged-in or not

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREF_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean isLoggedIn = preferences.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);
if (isLoggedIn) {
    //target to home page/login 
} else {
    //target to  tutorials
}
```

when the user logged in  set flag to `true`

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREF_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preferences.edit();
edit.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true);
edit.commit();
```

For more info visit [Official Doc -Storage Options - Using Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: would u tell me any example/demo app project available on internet

Comment: visit the official doc you will come to know. or Google - search for `android shared preferences`

Answer (score 1):

Use `SharedPreference` to save state, and after if use come again check if value is present in preference than do not show tutorial screen otherwise show

Comment: would u tell me any example/demo app project available on internet